# Is it reasonable to answer a question that simply says that you cannot reproduce the stated behaviour described in the question?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to know whether this answer is considered a valid answer: [E2009 Incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147523/e2009-incompatible-types-parameter-lists-differ/19147628#19147628)

The question presents some excerpts of code which the asker report do not compile. It is not immediately obvious why it does not and the question is why the compiler is rejecting the code.

The answer I am querying says:

> I am not able to reproduce the error on my XE2 using the following
>   test code:
>
> .... code removed ....
>
> Please provide an SSCCE that fails on your system.

At the time this answer was written, the question was rather more vague than it is now. The asker edited to add more details.

I'd like to know whether the community considers it reasonable to write such an answer? It seems to me like it ought to be a comment, but of course then the code could not be included.

**Update:** If the feeling is that it is a comment, and not an answer, should the answer be flagged as *not an answer*?

Comment: Sounds like a comment to me. The code would be tricky, but could be dumped on an external site and linked to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would agree that this should be a comment.

At least in my opinion, answers to this type of thing should cover one of two things (Both for a good answer, only one of the two would be meh or bad depending on context.)

1. Which bit of code is causing the stated behavior
2. *Why* that bit of code causes that behavior.

Any answer that states "Unable to reproduce" just tells me that the answerer doesn't know what the problem is either. It's not suitable for an answer, but it could be a useful comment (another data point for a possible future answer).

Comment: It could also tell you that there's no real problem in the question and it should be closed. But even in that case, it's still not an answer - it's a close reason.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a very strong idea what caused the problem for the OP - like a common configuration mistake, or a temporary failure - then it's often fine to post an answer.

If you don't know exactly what is going on, it's usually best to write a comment.